# Question wrong but my edit was rejected

Tags: discussion

I was trying to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495579/c-sharp-get-data-from-database-and-put-in-list) question, while answering I changed my answer after a back and forth in the comments with the OP.

My answer was fine now but the post itself made little sense (the OP wanted something totally different then the question intended). So the most sensible thing I could think of was to edit the post with the new information the OP had given me.

But then the  [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15888599) rejected. I can see why, as the reviewers will not look through all the comments on a post but the edit itself was correct.

So my question is: If in a situation like this, should I try and convince the OP to add the new information in the question (as soon as they have a working answer they are usually gone) or continue to edit as I did but risk rejection because of the lack of context.

*because I linked the question here my answer now has 0 as score, originally the OP had upvoted my answer*

Comment: Well, you changed the title to "c# Get data from database and put make labels" which doesn't make sense.

Comment: You'll learn to identify lousy questions and avoid them, as answering them tends to be a waste of time.  Like you wasted on this one.  If the OP isn't clear in what they want, what they tried and why it didn't work, don't bother doing anything other than asking them for clarification.

Comment: @code11 ah did not even notice that, but it certainly is more on point then make a list, as that was not at all what the op wanted. The other changed content in the post was certainly correct

Comment: One thing you can do is explain your reasoning for your edit in the Edit summary. You put *Changed post and tags to make the question clearer*, and people disagreed with the idea that the question was clearer.

Comment: As for _because I linked the question here my answer now has 0 as score, originally the OP had upvoted my answer_, it does look like other posts on there have also been downvoted.

Comment: You can't really do anything about the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect). As for your edit, you didn't explicitly state in your edit description that your changes came from the OP's comments. It probably wouldn't have hurt to briefly include why saying 'list' was wrong, esp. since the OP did originally say they wanted labels at the end of their question.

Comment: @BSMP I forgot to do this indeed, you can make this into an answer if you want

Comment: @Bugs I posted it here and no more then 20 seconds later I received a downvote. This post was fully inactive, I just think its childish that's all.

Comment: @EpicKip, some people will downvote answers on questions _they_ feel are bad. That's the risk of posting on META as linked above by BSMP. I personally think it's good that you stuck with the OP and helped them out. I can't however upvote because I don't actually know if it's useful (moral dilemma)

Comment: @Bugs All of the answers are just really bad answers.  They're all varying in what frameworks they're using (because the OP doesn't specify, so they're just guessing) and they're all using bad approaches, poor practices, unstable solutions, etc.  Even if the question had enough information to be answerable (it doesn't) there isn't a worthwhile answer there.

Comment: @Bugs Ah ok, this is my first time posting in META. I don't care about the downvote itself though (or upvote for that matter), its about how childish it is. No dilemma for you :).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142197/discussion-on-question-by-epickip-question-wrong-but-my-edit-was-rejected).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't explicitly state in your edit description that your changes came from the OP's comments. It probably wouldn't have hurt to briefly include why saying 'list' was wrong, especially since the OP did originally say they wanted labels at the end of their question.

Your edit to the title also introduced a grammar error and didn't remove the language tag at the beginning. The later isn't explicitly against the rules but it is encouraged that the [titles are regular sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

> So my question is: If in a situation like this, should I try and
>   convince the OP to add the new information in the question...

At this point, yes. They do have their answer but their question has been closed and has a score of -7. It would be in their best interest to improve this question.

Also, some of the comments here indicate the question has other issues that can only be addressed by the OP. If they don't fix their question, I'd leave it alone.